# Middleware header is not working with laravel 7

Tags: php, laravel

Below is my code;

**Route =>**

```
Route::get('displayImage', function () {
return response()->file('uploads/sss.png');
})->middleware(['myHeader']);
```

**myHeader =>**

```
class AddHeaders
{
/**
 * Handle an incoming request.
 *
 * @param Request $request
 * @param Closure $next
 * @return mixed
 */


  public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
  {
    if ($request->header('token') != '123'
    || $request->header('token1') != '1234') {
        return response([
            "status" => false,
            "message" => "unauthorized"
        ]);
    }
    return $next($request);
}
```

}

**Kernal.php**

```
    protected $routeMiddleware = [
    'myHeader' => AddHeaders::class,
    'age' => CheckAuth::class,
    ];
```

If I don't add a header in postman then it returns me image; my header is not working. Plz, help.

Comment: did u register your middleare in `kernal.php`.?

Comment: Yes, but route also working even i dont add header in postman @KamleshPaul

Comment: I also echo in header file and it gets printed while url access in browser

Comment: so u want to protect that route if someone don't add that header then will throw error that u want ?

Comment: Yes, I want that if anyone dont pass header in postman than route will throw error. I want to pass custom array of headers. plz see my code and suggest me @KamleshPaul

Comment: so check if the header is set in the middleware and if not throw an error ... its not really clear what you are trying to achieve

Comment: Can you plz check once my updated question I added two headers in it. can  you plz verify and tell me is this right way? @KamleshPaul

Comment: SO what is better way can you plz write your answer @lagbox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your code u r just addeding new header you are  not protecting so as
here is the code for this from postman

u need to pass

**in  Header**

```
key           | value

token | 123
or
token1 | 1234
```

like this your route will protect

```php
class AddHeaders
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param Request $request
     * @param Closure $next
     * @return mixed
     */


    public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
    {
        if ($request->header('token') == '123'   || $request->header('token1') == '1234') {
            return $next($request);
        }

        return response([
            "status" => false,
            "message" => "unauthorized"
        ]);
    }
}
```

Comment: and how can I add two headers together? just add with and condition in if statement ?

Comment: your should add header from postman and in sever it will check header is correct or not

Comment: but how can I add second header means header array?

Comment: i didn't get u in your code header is being added u can check in postman and if u need more u can add same code u r using

Comment: @VishalVaishnav yes that `123` u can change whatever u want

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220901/discussion-between-vishal-vaishnav-and-kamlesh-paul).

Answer (score 2):

You need to check if request has header using

```
$request->headers->has('your_header');
```

So middleware would look like below:

```
<?php

class AddHeaders
{
/**
 * Handle an incoming request.
 *
 * @param Request $request
 * @param Closure $next
 * @return mixed
 */


  public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
  {
    $has_token = $request->headers->has('token');
    $has_token1 = $request->headers->has('token1');

    if($has_token && $request->header('token') != '123' ||
        $has_token1 && $request->header('token1') != '1234' ||
        !$has_token || !$has_token1){
         return response([
            "status" => false,
            "message" => "unauthorized"
        ]);
    }

    return $next($request);
}
```

Comment: This is working even with one header. I want to restrict user if both will not applied then route have to give error.

Comment: @VishalVaishnav Ok, you didn't mention that in your question. Anyways, updated.